# How to get frame number given a timestamp using ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-processing

How can I get the frame number closest to a given time (relative to the start of the video) using ffmpeg? **The video has variable frame rate**. I do not need any other metadata or the actual frame (image) itself. Speed is more important than precision (unless the possible error is more than a couple of seconds).

Example:

Input

- video.mp4 (assuming ideal constant 30 fps for simplicity)
- 00:00:05 (HH:MM:SS)

Output

- 150

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```bash
ffmpeg -t 01:05 -i input.mp4 -nostats -vcodec copy -y -f rawvideo /dev/null 2>&1  |\
   grep frame |\
   awk '{print $2}'
```

This **ffmpeg** command takes your *input.mp4*, truncates it to -t (in the example above 01:05, and writes the file to */dev/null*. the `-y` overwrites whatever is on */dev/null*.

The **grep** command grabs the number of frames and **awk** gives you the 2nd "word" (space-delimited) on the line.

INPUT:
`ffmpeg -t 01:05 -i baywatch.mp4 -nostats -vcodec copy -y -f rawvideo /dev/null 2>&1 | grep frame | awk '{print $2}'`

OUTPUT:
`1559`

Comment: Do you have an idea how to make this platform independent or at least working on Windows?

Comment: the ffmpeg bit should work on windows.  but it outputs a lot more than you need - and you'll beed to filter with a regex for windows - which I am afraid I can't test for you :(

Comment: The regex I'm not worried about, but rather the /dev/null part that I don't fully understand.

Comment: That's just writing the new video to a file that no one cares about.  (and overwriting it each time. Pick a file name :D

Comment: you gotta love genius - thanks :D

Comment: 1. Is the comma necessary at the end of the command?
2. Why do I get "fps=28077" instead of the frame number?

Comment: What actually helps me is the following grep command: `ffmpeg -t 01:05 -i baywatch.mp4  -nostats -vcodec copy -y -f rawvideo /dev/null 2>&1 | grep -Po 'frame= *\K[0-9]*?(?= )'`

Comment: Nice hack! Does it save time/memory if we only encode the last, say, 2 seconds up to the time stamp?